# How do I access an Android internal style attributes via derived classes?

Tags: android, attr

I have subclassed preference, and created custom styleables in attrs.xml as follows:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyPreference">
    <attr name="myAttribute" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

and I can declare my Preference in xml as follows:

```
<com.my.project.MyPreference
    android:title="myTitle"
    namespace:myAttribute="@array/sleep_time_values" />
```

I can access the custom attribute just fine:

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyPreference, 0, 0);
thing = a.getText(R.styleable.MyPreference_myAttribute);
```

My question is: How do I access (in code) the internal android:title attribute specified in the xml definition above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Framework styleable arrays aren't public (or stable), but you can obtain a single public attribute using the same method for obtaining styled attributes. This should only be used to obtain a single attribute since the resources framework expects the attribute array to be in a specific order.

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
    attrs, new int[] { android.R.attr.title }, 0, 0);
String title = a.getText(0);
```