# How do I access the default android style from code?

Tags: android-styles

I'm trying to write my own version of android.widget.SeekBar by modifying the android source code: I can't use a derived class because I want to override some behaviour using private member variables which aren't visible to a derived class.

SeekBar, like most widgets, is styled. I want to change the behaviour, but not the style, so I need to get the default style that android.widget.SeekBar uses. The version in the android sources gets its style with something like this:-

```
final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
     attrs, R.styleable.SeekBar, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
final drawable thumb = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.SeekBar_thumb);
...
a.recycle();
```

Well `R.styleable` isn't accessible in user code. The answer to [How do I access an Android internal style attributes via derived classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415807/how-do-i-access-an-android-internal-style-attributes-via-derived-classes) suggests replacing `R.styleable.SeekBar` with
`new int[] { android.R.attr.seekBarStyle }`, but omits the `a.recycle()`, which I suspect may be wrong. It also says that only one style attribute at a time can be accessed in this way. Presumably you need to recycle the `TypedArray` each time

However SeekBar has a whole lot of style attributes, and the only thing exported from `r.attr` is `android.R.attr.seekBarStyle`, which is a single integer How do I get at the individual style attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values of default resources with some code like this:-

```
Resources res = getResources();
int defStyleAttr = res.getIdentifier(
   "android:attr/seekBarStyle", "", "android");
int resId = res.getIdentifier(
   "android:attr/thumb", "", "android");
TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(
   null, new int[] {resId}, defStyleAttr, 0);
final Drawable thumb = a.getDrawable(0);
a.recycle();
resId = res.getIdentifier(
   "android:attr/thumbTint", "", "android");
a = obtainStyledAttributes(
   null, new int[] {resId}, defStyleAttr, 0);
ColorStateList ThumbTintList = null;
ThumbTintList = a.getColorStateList(0);
a.recycle();
resId = res.getIdentifier(
   "android:attr/progressDrawable", "", "android");
a = obtainStyledAttributes(
   null, new int[] {resId}, defStyleAttr, 0);
final Drawable track = a.getDrawable(0);
a.recycle();
resId = res.getIdentifier(
   "android:attr/progressTint", "", "android");
a = obtainStyledAttributes(
   null, new int[] {resId}, defStyleAttr, 0);
ColorStateList progressTintList = null;
progressTintList = a.getColorStateList(0);
a.recycle();
resId = res.getIdentifier(
   "android:attr/paddingLeft", "", "android");
a = obtainStyledAttributes(
    null, new int[] {resId}, defStyleAttr, 0);
int paddingLeft = a.getInt(0, 0);
a.recycle();
resId = res.getIdentifier(
    "android:attr/paddingTop", "", "android");
a = obtainStyledAttributes(
   null, new int[] {resId}, defStyleAttr, 0);
int paddingTop = a.getInt(0, 0);
a.recycle();
resId = res.getIdentifier(
   "android:attr/paddingRight", "", "android");
a = obtainStyledAttributes(
   null, new int[] {resId}, defStyleAttr, 0);
int paddingRight = a.getInt(0, 0);
a.recycle();
resId = res.getIdentifier(
   "android:attr/paddingBottom", "", "android");
a = obtainStyledAttributes(
   null, new int[] {resId}, defStyleAttr, 0);
int paddingBottom = a.getInt(0, 0);
a.recycle();
```

`getIdentifier` is deprecated, but currently (4 January 2022) still works. Of course you need to know the names of the resources. These you can get from [R.styleable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable) by chopping off the initial class name and the underscore.

`getResources` and `obtainStyledAttributes` are member functions of `Context`, so if you aren't calling them from a class which inherits `Context` (Activities do, but widgets don't), you need a `context.` in front.

You can get the name for `defStyleAttr` by looking in the source code of the widget that you're replacing: it seems to be the name of the widget class with initial letter lower-cased and "Style" appended. If you're creating a completely new widget, 0 should do, but I haven't properly tested that.